# Votes Cast- by month, week and day

Tags: support, profile-page

In the profile page in any site from Stack Exchange, and under **Votes Cast** section, we can see something like the following:

[image: screen-shot]

What does *month*, *week* and *day* mean in this section?

Some users don't have similar titles, although they have voted before!

Do those have any meaning/ significance? or are those counted for any badges for example?

Comment: Votes cast this month, this week and this day.  There are badges for using 30 and 40 votes in a day; week and month are purely informational as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does month, week and day mean in this section?

Thats, I guess, simple: it means that user casted 2 votes this month, 3 votes this week and 1 vote that day.

> Some users don't have similar titles, although they have voted before!

If user hasn't voted this day, week, or month, corresponding section disappears.

> Do those have any meaning/ significance? or are those counted for any badges for example?

[Suffrage](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/804/suffrage) - use 30 votes in a day
[Vox Populi](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1108/vox-populi) - use 40 votes in a day